# Excel - Apply IF on all elements of the column before doing an Average

Tags: excel

```
     A
1    100.00%
2    0.00%
3    20.00%
```

I want to calculate the average of 3 elements, but before that, I want to apply the formula to every cell. 
If the value is more than 0 than use 100 in the calculation.
IF(Cellvalue>0,100,CellValue)

Result off the average of my column should be 66.7%

Answer (score 1):

Use countif() to count items greater than 0, then divide by the number of items (using count), then calculate %.

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A3,">0")/COUNT(A1:A3)*100
```

assuming your data is in cells A1 to A3.

Answer (score 1):

Try this array formula (finished with ctrl+shift+enter, not just enter).

```
=AVERAGE(--(A1:A3>0))
```

Answer (score 1):

`=SUMPRODUCT(AVERAGE(--(A1:A3>0)))`

`SUMPRODUCT` forces this to evaluate as an Array Formula.  This means it is the same as `=AVERAGE(--(A1>0), --(A2>0), --(A3>0))`

The `--` will convert from `TRUE`/`FALSE` to `1`/`0`

`(A1:A3>0)` or `(A1>0)` just checks "Is this value greater than zero", so `--(A1>0)` is just a short way to write `IF(A1>0, 1, 0)`